# Completely Positive Maps

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $X$ be an operator system. We denote the set of all unital completely positive maps from $X$ to $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ by $UCP_{n}(X)$. How can I characterize $UCP_{n}(M_{n}(\mathbb{C}))$ or $UCP_{n}(C([0,1],\mathbb{C}))$?

For example, is there any relationship between $UCP_{n}(M_{n}(\mathbb{C}))$ and the unitary group of $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ or between  $UCP_{n}(C([0,1],\mathbb{C}))$ and $M([0,1])$ (i.e. the set of all Borel measures on [0,1])?

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to your question but a comment.

For c.p. maps either from $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ or into $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, there is a rather simple 1-1 correspondence which may be useful:(you can find the proofs in Brown and Ozawa's exellent book(Proposition 1.5.12 and 1.5.14))

Let A be a C$^*$-algebra and let $ e_{i,j}$ be matrix units of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. A map $\varphi: M_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow A$ is c.p iff $[\varphi(e_{i,j})]$ is positive in $M_n(A)$.

If A is unital, a map $\phi: A\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is c.p. iff $\phi_n$, the extention of $\phi$ to $M_n(A)$, is positive.